# Can't shut down, reboot or sleep

Tags: suspend, shutdown, reboot

A few days ago my system (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 64bit) was working completely. Out of seemingly nowhere (I don't remember doing anything different from usual) my laptop started not going to sleep when I close the lid. The screen goes black but is still lit, the fans keep going, and my mouse still glows which should not happen in sleep mode, so the computer is not actually suspended. The problem is I can't wake the PC up from this state, anything I do doesn't seem to affect it in any way, and I have to force a shut down by holding the power button. I tried making it sleep from the shutdown menu, and still I get the same result. Every time my PC goes to "sleep" (I don't think it's actually going to sleep since I can hear the fans and I see the mouse glowing) I have no way of waking it up except with a forced shutdown.

I tried shutting it down and rebooting it as well, and I get similar results: the shut down screen pops up, with my computer's logo and the loading wheel, but after the loading wheel goes away the logo just stays there and the computer doesn't actually shut down, so again I have to force it to by pressing the power button.

I tried googling for answers but couldn't find much, and I have really no idea of where to start to diagnose the problem. Anyone has any idea of what could be happening?

edit: 
Running the `journalctl --grep='sleep|suspend|resume' --no-pager --since='-1hour'` command gave me this output:

```
ago 13 18:51:58 antonio-omen-ubuntu kernel: nvme 0000:3b:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
ago 13 18:53:55 antonio-omen-ubuntu systemd-logind[934]: Suspending...
ago 13 18:53:55 antonio-omen-ubuntu NetworkManager[861]: <info>  [1691945635.2727] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
ago 13 18:53:55 antonio-omen-ubuntu NetworkManager[861]: <info>  [1691945635.2728] device (eno1): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

ago 13 18:53:55 antonio-omen-ubuntu ModemManager[1018]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
ago 13 18:53:55 antonio-omen-ubuntu NetworkManager[861]: <info>  [1691945635.2842] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
ago 13 18:53:55 antonio-omen-ubuntu NetworkManager[861]: <info>  [1691945635.2843] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP

ago 13 18:53:55 antonio-omen-ubuntu NetworkManager[861]: <info>  [1691945635.2845] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
ago 13 18:53:55 antonio-omen-ubuntu NetworkManager[861]: <info>  [1691945635.4598] device (wlo1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
ago 13 18:53:55 antonio-omen-ubuntu NetworkManager[861]: <info>  [1691945635.5232] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

ago 13 18:53:56 antonio-omen-ubuntu systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
ago 13 18:53:56 antonio-omen-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
ago 13 18:53:56 antonio-omen-ubuntu systemd-sleep[5841]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
ago 13 18:53:56 antonio-omen-ubuntu kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
-- Boot f8879360ce544bcebc850319ae0a13ad --
ago 13 18:58:07 antonio-omen-ubuntu kernel: nvme 0000:3b:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
```

Comment: Close the lid wait a minute, open the lid  wait a minute, force shutdown, boot the computer and show us the output of `journalctl --grep='sleep|suspend|resume' --no-pager --since='-1hour'`, please.

Comment: it's too long for the comment, I added it as an edit to the post. thanks for the reply

Comment: It appears to be related to your internal nvme disk … see this related post https://askubuntu.com/q/1480075 and my answer to it for information … Your system however appears to be already configured for S3 power saving mode … I would suggest you boot to an older kernel and see if power management works again as this seems to be caused by some kind of update probably kernel or some hardware  firmware.

Comment: thank you it did work!