# Suspend not working (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: 22.04, suspend, dell

The machine won't wake after suspend.

This happens both when I close the lid, or when I suspend from the power off menu. As far as I can tell, the machine does go in suspend mode - the screen goes dark and built-in keyboard's backlight turns off. However, pressing buttons on the keyboard (even the built-in) or moving the mouse / touching the trackpad does not wake it up.

I don't see anything suspicious in the system log:

```
Sep 01 08:54:25 machine-Precision-5570 kernel: Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend
Sep 01 09:10:33 machine-Precision-5570 kernel: Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend
Sep 01 09:14:56 machine-Precision-5570 ModemManager[1261]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Sep 01 09:14:57 machine-Precision-5570 systemd-sleep[4698]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Sep 01 09:14:57 machine-Precision-5570 kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Sep 01 09:16:17 machine-Precision-5570 kernel: Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend
```

I found some posts that claim it's due to nvidia drivers, but I don't have any proprietary drivers installed.

I checked the BIOS but don't see anything relevant.

I tried enabling the USB devices power wakeup feature, but that didn't seem to do anything.

I'm running 22.04 on Dell Precision 5570.

***Edit:***
This appears to be kernel related. 6.2.0-31-generic and 6.2.0-32-generic exhibit the problem, but 5.19.0-50-generic does not - when I load that version of the kernel the machine shuts down just fine.

I'll file a bug report against Ubuntu - maybe updating the kernel would fix the issue, but I don't want to do that before I get some feedback if that's OK.

Comment: Try disabling bluetooth before the suspend.  I found my MSI will fail to resume if there is any bluetooth mouse activity first.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1480868

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a kernel related problem. I was running 6.2.0-32-generic.
When I switched to 5.19-50-generic, the issue went away.

I made it permanent by following this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1000735/433791

Basically:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Add the following 2 lines to the file

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

Then update the boot file:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart, then press "esc" when at the manufacturer logo. From the boot menu, select "Advanced" then select the kernel you want. That kernel will now be loaded at boot / restart.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware error and not an error on the OS. When the system is in hibernation or suspension pressing a key needs to be picked up by the system itself. Mind that a lot of Dell machines do NOT use wake-on-keyboard. Mine does not, not even in Windows.

> However, pressing buttons on the keyboard (even the built-in) or moving the mouse / touching the trackpad does not wake it up.

Make sure wake-on-keyboard is a feature of your machine.

---

I found this [external source](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000066378/why-is-there-no-wake-from-sleep-using-only-on-board-keyboard-and-touchpad-with-dell-eighth-generation-systems) also with a list of supported Dell systems. I don't see a Precision 5570 on this page (but there is an Inspiron 5570).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even if it's not, the power button should still wake it up - but it doesn't? I just tried it and the fan stayed on long after the screen went dark. I now suspect maybe it's not going into suspend mode despite what the logs say. What do you think?

Comment: Another issue I'm having that might be relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484374/restarting-freezes-due-to-snap