Limit Ubuntu RAM Usage (for the whole OS, not a process)
I have 24GB of ram, and using KDE.
For some reason, I want my OS to see only 10GB of RAM. When I get free -mh it tells me that my physical memory is 10GB.
How do I do that?

Note: My problem is with sleeping and swap space. My swap partition is 10GB, and I don't have an extra 14GB to give to swap. On the other hand, my KDE doesn't ever use more than 5GB of RAM, so I think making my OS to see only 10GB of RAM is a good fix for both sleeping and hibernation.
Thank you in advance.

Look into MemoryMax= in Control Groups … See related How to find cgroup memory limit in Ubuntu 22.04? … However, that might not be the best solution for your issue as this looks like an XY question … I suggest you focus on explaining the problem you’re facing and let the community suggest solutions rather than asking about your attempted solution.

Add the boot option mem=10G to the 'linux line' in /boot/grub/grub.cfg. But some RAM is probably dedicated to the graphics, so mem will show less than 10 G.

@Raffa Yes Sir you're right. I'm asking about my attempt solution, but I searched a lot about my problem with sleep (when my system goes to sleep, it won't come back. The screen flashes, remain black and I can't see no login screen. I have to force shutdown it using the power button. My whole programs get closed. Idk why sleep doesn't work normally). I searched and found many people had the same problem and found no usable solution for it. If you know any websites that helps me, I'd appreciate a lot.

@Raffa I also searched about cgroup, but it's for processes not the whole system.

@sudodus Thanks man. I searched the whole Internet and didn't find it. I have also watched videos on LPIC1/2 and nobody talked about that. How do I learn other options of grub? Or more generally in Ubuntu? Any courses you have passed?

A suspend/sleep issue can have multiple causes and there is no one fits all solution, but you need to investigate/debug ... Please see for example https://askubuntu.com/a/1478294 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1480868 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1480257 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1218889 for how to investigate and some possible reasons which as you will see differ from one situation to another, so you need to find what exactly cases this problem on your system and attempt a proper fix accordingly (notice that on some platforms this issue might be linked to hardware firmware support) ...

... Also limiting system memory using kernel boot parameters will make the rest of RAM off-limits and unusable by sleep/suspend which you seem to want as you seem to expect the rest of the memory i.e. 14 G to be available during sleep/suspend ... Well that isn't possible i.e. if some portion of memory isn't available to the kernel in the first place, it's not going to be available to any other process ... Therefore, limiting system memory in that way can never be a possible solution to such problem AFAIK.

@MohammadKholghi, No particular courses about Ubuntu, but I worked a lot with computers (doing simulation of manufacturing processes) until I retired. And now I enjoy using Ubuntu and helping others who use Ubuntu. - I answered by providing the solution you asked for, but the other helper, Raffa, is offering even better advice, to help you solve the problem, that makes you ask how to limit the usage of RAM.
